# mariadb cant turn on error_log

Tags: log-files, mariadb

I want to turn on error logging for mariadb to resolve "unable to connect to database" errors

I can turn on General Log and Slow Query Log in mariadb no problem.
However when I restart mariadb they are turned off again. (maybe thats supposed to happen ?)

I cant turn on log_error at all (/var/log/mysqld.log)

```
SET log_error='/var/log/mysqld.log';
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'log_error' is a read only variable

SET GLOBAL log_error='/var/log/mysqld.log';
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'log_error' is a read only variable
```

I've set file permission

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysqld.log
```

but still get the same error

Comment: Please post your complete my.cnf file and any other file that is included in startup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I can turn on General Log and Slow Query Log in mariadb no problem.
> However when I restart mariadb they are turned off again. (maybe thats supposed to happen ?)

<sub>Maybe you should read something about server system variables and what SET is do to understand that. Who knows.</sub>

With SET statement you change variable's value for current session or globally for runtime period only while server is running.

So if you need to set variable permanently you should change it in the server's configuration file. It applies to other databases too like mysql, mariadb, postgresql, oracle.

> I cant turn on log_error at all
> SET log_error='/var/log/mysqld.log';
> ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'log_error' is a read only variable

1. It is server system **variable** is readonly not the file.
   It means you cannot change it at runtime by definition.
2. You should check variables list to know what variable you can change at runtime (see Dynamic:yes|no):
   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#log_error
   or query database itself about that like here: https://mariadb.org/mariadb-10-1-1-system-variables-and-their-metadata/

So you should set `log_error` in mariadb configuration file.

```
my.cnf
[mysqld]
general_log=1
slow_query_log=1
log_error=/path/to/file
```

Comment: thanks - I have added lines singly and together to /etc/mysql/my.cnf    but when I restart mariadb it doesnt work and I get an error message until I remove them.
Even commands that work in mariadb give an error message when added to my.cnf
SET log_error = on
 SET GLOBAL log_output = 'FILE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL general_log = ‘1’;

I will read the links you added.

Comment: You should write as `general_log=1` `log_output=/path/to/file` without SET, GLOBAL, quoting, spaces and other junk. **Read examples before doing something** https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#example-minimal-option-file  You set general_log twice. `SET statement` **is valid in SQL session only**. You are not very attentive in what you doing

Comment: thanks I did try combinations with and without SET etc or ; or ''.  I will read the info in your links and do it again.  I'm sure I'll get it eventually !

Comment: You use wrong variable names and wrong formatting in `my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

Of course gapsf is correct - I made an error and did not include [mysqld]

adding the following to the bottom of my.cnf works perfectly

```
[mysqld]
general_log=1
slow_query_log=1
log_error=var/log/mysqld.log
```

check settings with command

```
sudo mysql -se "SHOW VARIABLES" | grep -e log_error -e general_log -e
```

outputs

```
slow_query_log
general_log     ON
general_log_file        lamp-wp3.log
log_error       var/log/mysqld.log
slow_query_log  ON
slow_query_log_file     lamp-wp3-slow.log
```

Thanks, now I can check for errors.

Comment: If your system is busy, general_log=ON will use much space recording the general log.  Turn OFF as soon as you can to avoid filling your media with something you will never use.  Also delete any General Log to return space to your storage device.